# Can I clone a 1TB hard drive with Ubuntu and Windows 8.1 to a sshd on a laptop?

Tags: dual-boot, windows, hard-drive, 14.10, clone

I am using Ubuntu 14.10 and will upgrade to Ubuntu 15.04 this afternoon. I was curious while looking at hard drives and was seeing that SSHD drives are the perfect mix of hard drive and solid state technologies. My only questions are how do I clone my 1TB HDD to a 1TB SSHD without losing a little bit of data or a whole partition and will it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out Clonezilla [here](http://clonezilla.org/), I've used it to clone Windows+Ubuntu installs on a single disk before. It even offers to attempt clone the bootloader as well. Assuming secure boot is off it should work fairly well for you.

Comment: I am not using MBR... I am using GPT, could it still work? If not what workarounds do I do?

Comment: I read their website, they said they support it. Worth trying, since cloning FROM an drive won't harm any data